# can't remove target from the self in cocos2d-iphone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray

I use following code to create some sprites

```
-(void)dologic
{

 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
    CCSprite *target = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"pig.png"];
    int x = arc4random() % 320;
    int y = arc4random() % 300;
    target.position = ccp(x, y);
    [self addChild:target];
    [_targets addObject:target];//_targets is nsmutablearray
 }
}


- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];
  for (CCSprite *target in _targets) {
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(target.boundingBox, location)) {
        [_targets removeAllObjects];
        [self removeChild:target cleanup:YES];
        [self dologic];
    }
}
```

when touch any sprite, all sprites will be removed from the self first, and then call `dologic` to create three new sprites again, but my code can only remove the target that i touched, how can i remove all sprites when i touch the screen?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are modifying the array while iterating it, which is not a good practice.

If you want to remove all targets upon touching any of them, you can try this:

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];
    BOOL touchedASprite = NO;
    for (int i = 0; i < [_targets count] && !touchedASprite; ++i) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint((CCSprite*)[_targets objectAtIndex:i].boundingBox, location)) {
            touchedASprite = YES;
        }
    }
    if (touchedASprite) {
        for (CCSprite *target in _targets) {
            [self removeChild:target cleanup:YES];
        }
        [_targets removeAllObjects];
        [self doLogic];
    }
}
```

Comment: ` if (CGRectContainsPoint((CCSprite*)[_targets objectAtIndex:i].boundingBox, location)) {` this line shows error: property 'boundingBox' not found on object of type 'id'

Comment: add `()` out of `(CCSprite*)[_targets objectAtIndex:i]` can fix this bug. but this code can not delete all sprites.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to remove objects in a array while browsing all objects of it, you should do like this:

```
for (int i = (int)_targets.count - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    CCSprite *target = _targets[i];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(target.boundingBox, location)) {
        [_targets removeAllObjects];
        [self removeChild:target cleanup:YES];
        [self dologic];
    }
}
```

**Be careful**: `[NSArray count]` returns a unsigned number, when `[NSArray count]` returns **0**, (`[NSArray count]-1`) is **NOT** -1, should cast it to int